# Can anyone tell me how to make the printed screen blue?

Tags: python, function, audio, pygame, collision

This is the original question:
[image: This is the question]

As shown above, I need to print a blue screen. This is what I did:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

blue = (0, 0, 255)

size = (width, height) = (640, 640)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

""" Game Drawing """
screen.fill(blue)
pyagme.draw.rect(screen, color, [x, y, 50, 50])
pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, [mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50])
pygame.display.flip()
```

However, only a black screen is produced... Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like you want us to give you the raw code.. Please attempt it yourself then show us what you have tried and what specific questions you have bout any failed attempts, and we will be happy to help.

Comment: thank you for all the comments, and I have now edited my question. Sorry if I did anything wrongly...as I'm new to this forum. Thank you again

Comment: I'm not sure... Have you made sure yo have the most recent version of pygame?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's fix the errors in your code.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
blue = (0, 0, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
size = (640, 640)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

screen.fill(blue)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, [0,590, 50, 640])
pygame.display.update()

crashed = False
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
            pygame.quit()
```

And now your screen is blue. And you have a red square.